# Symfony 3 set Translation from own dictionary, and switch with url

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I creating new easy web with Symfony 3 (I am new with Symfony, I check some post in google, doc in Symfony or here on StackOverflow but nothing does not work) and I need set only:

- url routing `/` as default `en` lang and `/cs` for czech lang, `/fr` for french lang, with universal option to switch another page for example `/contacts, /fr/contacts /fr/about` etc
- use my own translation yml file located in `app/Resources/translations`
- use localization in twig like this `{{ 'someone'|trans }}`

I set **config.yml**:

```
parameters:
     locale: cs

framework:
     translator: { fallbacks: [cs] }
```

**messages.en.yml**

```
contacts: Contacts
```

and call it in **base.html.twig**:

```
<a href="#">{{ contacts|trans }}</a>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: were is the question ?

Comment: in the list, translation does not work and I dont know where is  a problem or what is missing (for example in controller), I think then I need some routing string

Comment: you are falling back to cs , do you have `messages.cs.yml` file ? also try clearing cache to be sure the problem is persistant

Comment: I try it all, and nothing help, default lang is ok and works but if I add /en/ param to url I got theme message `No route found for "GET /en/"`, exit some universal route for language translate support ? i have now only this in routing.yml

`app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working solution

**config.yml:**

```
parameters:
    locale: cs
    app_locales: cs|en
    web_root: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/'

framework:
    #esi: ~
    translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
    default_locale: "%locale%"
```

**In controller:**

```
    /**
     * 
     * @Route(
     *     "/", name="home_cs",   
     *     defaults={"_locale":"%locale%"}
     *     )
     * @Route(
     *     "/{_locale}/", name="home",      
     *     requirements={"_locale":"%app_locales%"}
     *     ) 
     * 
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request) {
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig');
    }
```

**Template header.html.twig:**

```
<select class="selectpicker pull-right lang" data-width="fit">
                                    <option data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cz"></span>' {% if app.request.getLocale() == 'cs' %}selected{% endif %} >cs</option>
                                    <option data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span>' {% if app.request.getLocale() == 'en' %}selected{% endif %} >en</option>
                                </select>
```